# Access Private NIC Through Public NIC

Tags: vpn, routing, port-forwarding, remote-access, network-adapter

I am totally stumped. I have tried playing with the routing table but no luck.

I am using Windows 7.

I have a computer (#1) with two NICs (A and B). A is a wireless interface that connects to a WiFi network that allows internet access. B is an ethernet port that a device plugs into. The device gives B an IP address. The two interfaces have different IP addresses and are on different subnets.

I'd like to access the device attached to B from a remote computer (#2). Essentially, I want to send and receive packets to device B.

I have VPN access to A. How do I access the device on NIC B from computer #2?

I hope my description is clear.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to "bridge" the two NICs.

If you open "Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections" you can usually do this by selecting both the NICs and then right-click -> Bridge Connections.

Note that you will most likely lose your VPN access through NIC A during the setup process, so you should do this with local access to computer #1.